# Custom ValidationAttribute not firing IsValid function call in view model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have created my own custom `ValidationAttribute`:

```
public class UrlValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public UrlValidationAttribute() {}

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        var text = value as string;
        Uri uri;

        return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) && 
                Uri.TryCreate(text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri));
    }
}
```

**I am using that on one of my models and it works perfectly.** However, now I am attempting to use it on a view model:

```
public class DeviceAttribute
{
    public DeviceAttribute(int id, attributeDefinition, String url)
    {
        ID = id;
        Url = url;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [UrlValidation]
    public String Url { get; set; }
}
```

The view model is used in the partial view like this:

```
@model List<ICMDB.Models.DeviceAttribute>

<table class="editor-table">

@foreach (var attribute in Model)
{
    <tr>

        @Html.HiddenFor(a => attribute.ID)

        <td class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => attribute.Url)
        </td>

        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => attribute.Url)            
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => attribute.Url)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

For some unknown reason, while the constructor for UrlValidationAttribute fires, the IsValid function doesn't fire. Any ideas?

**Edit:** On further investigation, it seems this is happening because the `DeviceAttribute` view model is actually the view model for a partial.  The full page is passed a different view model that contains the list of `DeviceAttribute` view models.  So when my controller action is called, the full page view model is constructed and its values filled, but no `DeviceAttribute` view models are constructed, hence why no validation is run.

Comment: Perhaps try overriding @protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)@ - this is the method that should be overriden for ValidationAttribute's. NB: Make sure you call the ctor of ValidationResult with the member information found in the validation context.

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work.  I think it's something to do with the fact that this is in a partial view, so the `List<DeviceAttribute>` doesn't get passed back to the controller for validation...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend you using editor templates instead of writing foreach loops. I suppose that your main view model looks something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<DeviceAttribute> Devices { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now in your main view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="editor-table">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Devices)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DeviceAttribute.cshtml`):

```
@model DeviceAttribute
<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)

    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Url)
    </td>

    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Url)            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Url)
    </td>
</tr>
```

And your POST action takes the view model back:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Now the default model binder will successfully bind all values in the view model and kick validation.

Here's a [nice blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) about templates.